# OpenGL ES 2.0 (Java, Android): draw texture over a square/rectangle

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I tested the OpenGL ES 2.0 demo project here : https://github.com/JimSeker/opengl/tree/master/HelloOpenGLES20

It draws a triangle and a square with a uniform color.

Class to draw the Square : https://github.com/JimSeker/opengl/blob/master/HelloOpenGLES20/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/opengl/Square.java

Now, I would like a modified Square.java class in order to have a rectangle (size 1005x20) instead of a square. And I want to cover this rectangle with a  repetitive texture (size 10x10) over its height and width (100.5 textures over the length and 2 over the width).

Anybody could help me ?

Comment: where do you call `public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix)` method ?

Comment: Open the project in Android Studio. You will see that the draw method is called in the renderer here : https://github.com/JimSeker/opengl/blob/master/HelloOpenGLES20/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/opengl/MyGLRenderer.java

Comment: Welcome to SO! When asking questions; instead of posting GitHub link or the whole project; create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve